# Annotation button segue

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am making an app that with numerous locations on a MKMapView with a button that segues to different view controllers. I have created the map, annotations and buttons on the annotations but am having trouble segueing the buttons to separate view controllers.

I have coded the following:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

                func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
                    print("Button tapped")

                if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
                    if annotation.title == "Mystics Beach"{



                        performSegueWithIdentifier("mysticsa", sender: nil)

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: make breakpoint and see if your segue got called?

Comment: What kind of trouble?

Comment: I could only segue all buttons to one view controller not individual buttons to individual views @Mr.UB

Comment: How do you want to separate the segues, on what basis?

Comment: And `performSegueWithIdentifier("mysticsa", sender: nil)` is working?

Comment: remove " if annotation.title == "Mystics Beach" " condition  in code and have a check